# In Linux, how to redirect wall output in script to file?

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I'm trying to log events in a bash script with the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
...
echo "Photo backup successfully finished on $(date)" | wall
...
} &>> "/var/log/$(basename "$0").log" &
```

however, in the log file, the corresponding line instead appears as:

```
wall: cannot get tty name: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

It seems that wall outputs can't be directed to file.

How can I get this to work? (Be able to post to wall AND log message to file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility is to use "tee -a" instead of ">>".  For example:

`echo "Hello world"|tee -a myfile.log|wall`

Comment: Thanks, this works, but now I have "|tee -a $LOGFILE" all over my script (once for each command whose output I want to have logged). If possible, it would be great if I could avoid such repetitive code.

Comment: create a function then pass in the logname as an argument :)

Comment: @MatthewPigram I'm not sure if that will serve my original purpose. I need to selectively direct some of those command outputs to wall as well.

Comment: @silvernightstar create the function with 2 passable parameters the filename and a boolean value (0 | 1) indicating if it should use wall or not, use an if statement to handle the correct call

Comment: Q: What's preventing you from `|tee -a /var/log/$(basename "$0").log`?

Comment: @paulsm4 If I put my wall command after everything i.e. `|tee -a /var/log/$(basename "$0").log|wall`, everything would be broadcast. On the other hand, if I keep my wall commands within the code block enclosed by the curly braces, the commands they operate on don't get logged to file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it just because current terminal owned with other user/group than you run the sommand from. Following examples tested in Fedora 21.

check for your TTY that used like with "w"

```
$ w
 09:20:21 up 10:34,  2 users,  load average: 0.22, 0.27, 0.35
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
alex     pts/0     08:38   41:17   0.27s 13.46s /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
alex     pts/1     08:39    5.00s  0.81s 13.46s /usr/bin/xfce4-terminal
```

and then

```
$ ls -l /dev/pts/*
total 0
crw--w----. 1 alex tty  136, 0 Mar 13 09:18 0
crw--w----. 1 alex tty  136, 1 Mar 13 09:22 1
```

then you can just add users who should send messages to wall, to group "tty"

```
mcedit /etc/group
...
tty:alex,nut
...
```